# add and display all text in toast after enter all text in edit text in all edite text view in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText edtPasscode1;
    EditText edtPasscode2;
    EditText edtPasscode3;
    EditText edtPasscode4;
    Button button1;
    StringBuilder sb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtPasscode1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edtPasscode2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edtPasscode3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        edtPasscode4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(edtPasscode1.getText().toString());
        sb.append(edtPasscode2.getText().toString());
        sb.append(edtPasscode3.getText().toString());
        sb.append(edtPasscode4.getText().toString());

        edtPasscode1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0 & edtPasscode1.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append(s);
                    edtPasscode1.clearFocus();
                    edtPasscode2.requestFocus();
                    edtPasscode2.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 1) {

                    sb.deleteCharAt(0);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0) {

                    edtPasscode1.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

        edtPasscode2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0 & edtPasscode2.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append(arg0);
                    edtPasscode2.clearFocus();
                    edtPasscode3.requestFocus();
                    edtPasscode3.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sb.deleteCharAt(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0) {

                    edtPasscode2.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

        edtPasscode3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0 & edtPasscode3.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append(s);
                    edtPasscode3.clearFocus();
                    edtPasscode4.requestFocus();
                    edtPasscode4.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sb.deleteCharAt(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0) {

                    edtPasscode3.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });


        edtPasscode4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (sb.length() == 0 & edtPasscode4.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append(arg0);
                    edtPasscode4.clearFocus();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sb.append(arg0).toString(), 10000).show();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

This is my code  i have 4 edit text when i enter value in first edit text key cursor moving to another edit text when enter second edit text  key cursor move to third text when enter third edit text  key cursor move to 4th i want when i enter 4th edit text i want do display all text value in toast i.e edittext1.gettext()+edittext2.gettext()+edittext3.gettext()+edittext4.gettext() =1234 where 1 is enter in edit text1 2 is enter in 2 3 is enter 3 4 is enter 4 respectively please suggest me where am doing wrong.why its not displaying all text value it display onlu 34 please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `EditText` `TextWatcher`s you are using "beforeTextChanged" to delete the first indexed value of the string:

```
sb.deleteCharAt(0);
```

This deletes the chars entered for 1 and 2. You do not do this in `EditText` 4, so your result includes 3 & 4, as stated.

You should probably not use this. The problem is that you are trying to "automatically" change focus, and this could be a bad user experience if a wrong character is entered. That appears to be what you are trying to account for.

You should probably not try to automatically move the cursor from one space to another, or simply "enable" each one when a character is entered and prevent more than 1 character from being entered. Then use `afterTextChanged` on the 4th `EditText` like you are now.

EDIT:

Because your are using `TextWatcher` you should not do anything in "beforeTextChanged" except limit the number of characters typed. In "onTextChanged" you can monitor for valid characters. You should probably only attempt to change focus in "afterTextChanged" but even that is not really "recommended" since an attempt to type 2 characters (like regaining focus after you type a "3" and then simply typing a "4") will probably lead to annoying/unexpected user experience.

EDIT 2:

You still have bugs in your code - for example, you are doing this check "sb.length() == 0" in your 2nd EditText - but it shoul have a length of 1, right? In my answer, I suggested that you don't try to "build" the string until the Toast because "requesting focus" is not the same as disabling, so you are likely to get weird results until you get your interaction (UX) logic correct.

In other words, you asked "why is it displaying only '34'" and I answered that. Now you have a different bug when you build the string. You will have more bugs if users "go back" to an edittext and delete a character because your StringBuilder always appends and never deletes. You will also have to keep track of which "index" to modify based on where the user is.

Also, you "afterTextChanged" code doesn't make sense - you try to "requestFocus" when the StringBuilder is length "0" but that should only happen if you ever delete from `sb`, which you don't. So I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it doesn't look like it's doing what you want.

EDIT 3:

Here is an example that should help. Don't use StringBuilder at all for now.

In `edtPasscode4` do this:

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                 edtPasscode1.getText().toString() +
                 edtPasscode2.getText().toString() +
                 edtPasscode3.getText().toString() +
                 edtPasscode4.getText().toString() +
                 , 10000).show();
        }
```

Comment: what i have to do for this should i remove sb.deleteCharAt(0);

Comment: where am doing what i have to remove

Comment: I edited my answer. The short version - YES, remove all of those deleteCharAt calls...

Comment: uh - what does "not working" mean? Same result? If so, not possible - something must have changed unless you made other changes, did not build properly, etc...

Comment: Yes - remove the "deleteCharAt" from all EditText. Also, build the final string from all EditText.getText().toString() in the 4th case; there is no purpose in keeping a dynamically built string of the "current state" of the string, is there?? Just build it when you're done...

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/32DxAZ2dit3dp8svsJB4tAi what haapn in this code in edittext2 two time text entering

Comment: I edited my response. You have several issues, but I think I answered your original question...

Comment: I just want add all 4 edit text suppose i have enter in edittext1=1,edittext2=2,edittext3=3 and edittext4=4 respectively then it should Print 1234 in toast .

Comment: You are making this complicated if that is all you are really trying to do. See my 3rd edit. Just concatenate the strings when you want it displayed...

Comment: Thanx i was really did silly mistake thanx for give me suggestion